# Query view counts give incorrect results

Tags: bug, search, views

Consider [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhortonworks%5D+-%5Bhortonworks-data-platform%5D+is%3Aquestion+views%3A10..10), which yields 3 questions (today).

```
[hortonworks] -[hortonworks-data-platform] is:question views:10..10
```

[image: query deets]

Anticipating the Meta effect, the view counts will change, but here's what those three questions have at the moment:

[image: One]

[image: Two]

[image: Three]

**NONE** of those are 10 views. This appears to be a bug.

You may ask, "Why are you asking for such a small number, anyway, why not just ask for larger numbers?" I've been cleaning up these tags, and am trying to organize my work so I cover all questions once - I find that stepping through by view count allows me to batch questions into chunks I can handle between real-life interruptions.

Comment: We don't re-index questions for search when *only* views change. Searching by views isn't terribly precise as a result. Not in a position to verify at the moment, but my money's on [status-bydesign] here.

Comment: @Adam while I tend to agree, I think this renders the whole "search by views" operator useless. If it can't be precise, better just remove it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not sure I agree. It's still broadly useful at larger magnitudes.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to fix your real-life interruptions...

Answer (score 3):

As a developer says in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274295/query-view-counts-give-incorrect-results#comment891452_274295):

> We don't re-index questions for search when only views change

This makes sense, and means the views we see in search results are the views when the question was last indexed, i.e. when there was some activity in the question. (e.g. edit, new answer, etc.)

This makes the bug [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).